# GroupBy in PySpark vs groupby pandas

Tags: pyspark, group-by, pandas-groupby

I can't find the difference between pandas `.groupby()` and PySpark `.groupBy()` (when applied to a DataFrame). Is there any difference? I'm getting the same results. If there is a difference, how do I know when to use which, in case I'm dealing with PySpark at the same time.
Thanks!

Comment: if you're worried about the keyword, see [this doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy) -- `groupby()` is an alias to `groupBy()` in pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in the semantics. The difference lies within Pandas (Single Machine) and Spark (Framework for Distributed Computing).